# Frequencies in Python

Tags: python

```
def frequencies(data):

    data.sort()

    count = 0
    previous = data[0]

    print("data\tfrequency") # '\t' is the TAB character

    for d in data:
        if d == previous:
            # same as the previous, so just increment the count
            count += 1
        else:
            # we've found a new item so print out the old and reset the count
            print(str(previous) + "\t" + str(count))
            count = 1

        previous = d
```

So I have this frequency code, but its leaving off the last number in my list every time.

It may have something to do with where I start previous or possibly where I reset previous to d at the end.

Answer (score 3):

For the last group of elements, you never print them out, because you never find something different after it. You would need to repeat the printout thing after your loop.

But that is rather academic; in real world, you would be much more likely to use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(data)
for key in counter:
    print("%s\t%d" % (key, counter[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count items in a list/sequence using `count`. So your code can be simplified to look like this:

```
def frequencies(data):
    unique_items = set(data)
    for item in unique_items:
        print('%s\t%s' % (item, data.count(item)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to keep the code the way it is currently set up, just fix a line of code